# Compile FFMPEG + x264 - undefined references

Tags: android, compilation, include, ffmpeg, x264

I have been trying to find a solution online for a couple of days with no luck. I am using Ubuntu and trying to compile the latest FFMPEG stable version (1.0.1) with x264 support. I made sure I uninstalled any existing x264 then I downloaded the latest x264 source and compiled it with the following config:

```
./configure --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --enable-shared \
    --enable-static \
    --disable-gpac \
    --extra-cflags=" -I$ARM_INC -fPIC -DANDROID -fpic -mthumb-interwork -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fno-short-enums -D__ARM_ARCH_5__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5T__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5E__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__ -Wno-psabi -march=armv5te -msoft-float -mthumb -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -DANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -MMD -MP " \
    --extra-ldflags=" -nostdlib -Bdynamic -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,nocopyreloc -Wl,-soname,/usr/lib/libz.so -Wl,-rpath-link=$ARM_LIB,-dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker -L$ARM_LIB -lc -lm -ldl -lgcc" \
    --cross-prefix=${ARM_PRE}- \
    --disable-asm \
    --host=arm-linux \

    make clean
    make install
```

All goes well, and I checked the installed version:

```
x264 -V
    x264 0.129.x
    built on Dec 27 2012, gcc: 4.6.1
    configuration: --bit-depth=8 --chroma-format=all
    x264 license: GPL version 2 or later
```

I then try to compile FFMPEG with the following options:

```
./configure --target-os=linux \
    --enable-libx264 \
    --enable-gpl \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --extra-cflags="-I/home/tishu/Workspaces/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/jni/ffmpeg-1.0.1/android/armv7-a/include -I/home/tishu/Workspaces/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/jni/x264 -O3 -fpic -DANDROID -DHAVE_SYS_UIO_H=1 -Dipv6mr_interface=ipv6mr_ifindex -fasm -Wno-psabi -fno-short-enums  -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=300 $OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS " \
    --extra-ldflags="-Wl,-rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L/home/tishu/Workspaces/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/jni/ffmpeg-1.0.1/android/armv7-a/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib -nostdlib -lc -lm -ldl -llog" \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --extra-libs="-lgcc" \
    --arch=arm \
    --cc=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc \
    --cross-prefix=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --nm=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm \
    --sysroot=$PLATFORM \
```

The configure and make clean/make install work well, but when I try to create the .so file the following command fails:

```
/home/tishu/Apps/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld 
    -rpath-link=./android/armv7-a/usr/lib -L/home/tishu/Apps/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/lib -soname libffmpeg.so -shared -nostdlib  -z,noexecstack -Bsymbolic \
    --whole-archive --no-undefined -o ./android/armv7-a/libffmpeg.so libavcodec/libavcodec.a libavformat/libavformat.a libavutil/libavutil.a libswscale/libswscale.a -lc -lm -lz -ldl -llog  \
    --warn-once \
    --dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker /home/tishu/Apps/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/libgcc.a
```

This fails with the following output:

```
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(libx264.o): In function `X264_frame':
/home/tishu/Workspaces/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/jni/ffmpeg-1.0.1/libavcodec/libx264.c:159: undefined reference to `x264_picture_init'
/home/tishu/Workspaces/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/jni/ffmpeg-1.0.1/libavcodec/libx264.c:179: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_reconfig'
/home/tishu/Workspaces/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/jni/ffmpeg-1.0.1/libavcodec/libx264.c:190: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_encode'
/home/tishu/Workspaces/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/jni/ffmpeg-1.0.1/libavcodec/libx264.c:196: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_delayed_frames'
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(libx264.o): In function `encode_nals':
/home/tishu/Workspaces/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/jni/ffmpeg-1.0.1/libavcodec/libx264.c:101: undefined reference to `x264_bit_depth'
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(libx264.o): In function `X264_close':
/home/tishu/Workspaces/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/jni/ffmpeg-1.0.1/libavcodec/libx264.c:231: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_close'
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(libx264.o): In function `X264_init':
/home/tishu/Workspaces/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/jni/ffmpeg-1.0.1/libavcodec/libx264.c:284: undefined reference to `x264_param_default'
/home/tishu/Workspaces/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/jni/ffmpeg-1.0.1/libavcodec/libx264.c:292: undefined reference to `x264_param_default_preset'
/home/tishu/Workspaces/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/jni/ffmpeg-1.0.1/libavcodec/libx264.c:314: undefined reference to `x264_param_parse'
/home/tishu/Workspaces/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/jni/ffmpeg-1.0.1/libavcodec/libx264.c:459: undefined reference to `x264_param_apply_fastfirstpass'
/home/tishu/Workspaces/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/jni/ffmpeg-1.0.1/libavcodec/libx264.c:490: undefined reference to `x264_param_apply_profile'
/home/tishu/Workspaces/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/jni/ffmpeg-1.0.1/libavcodec/libx264.c:533: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_open_129'
/home/tishu/Workspaces/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/jni/ffmpeg-1.0.1/libavcodec/libx264.c:544: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_headers'
```

The x264 version it is looking for (129) is the one installed and compiled succesfully with --eanable-shared. Obviously all compiles fine when I do not include libx64.

**Question:** How can I specify the include path for the last command? I tried adding the path to $PATH and also adding this as an argument with no luck: -I/home/tishu/Workspaces/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/jni/x264

Thanks

Comment: Some more digging on how ld works did the job : http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_95.html - I just added libx64.a to the list of files to link and it works now

Comment: The `undefined reference` messages can indicate that you may have two different versions of x264 installed at the same time.

Comment: If you correctly build x264 for ARM, you will not be able to run it to receive the second exposure. Either you failed to uninstall the x86 version, or have rebuilt it. At any rate, you can probably fix your ffmpeg build by simply adding `/home/tishu/Workspaces/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/jni/x264/libx264.so` to `--extra-ldflags=`

Comment: Hi Tishu :) I am trying to play .ts file from Android app.For this I have used FFmpeg library from https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg. I have managed to compile & run the example app successfully.But the app doesn't play .ts files.Can you please guide me what should I do to play .ts file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For followers (not even android but similar message),

```
/.../mingw-w64-i686/lib/gcc/.../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: 
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(libx264.o):libx264.c:(.text+0x3c): 
undefined reference to `x264_bit_depth'
: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_open_152'
```

appears this constant was "dropped" early 2017 see https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6966 and https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6932

fix: update ffmpeg, or downdate libx264...or something...

though these days it's supposed to kind of support older version of libx264 as well...